# why won't javascript won't work (Rails 7 with esbuild)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm pretty new to Rails (version 7.0.4.2 with ruby 3.2.0, on an Intel-based Macbook Pro running Monterey 12.6). Here's a minimal example causing me problems:

I start a new project by doing
`rails new project_name --j esbuild -c bootstrap`

After the installation completes I make a minimal bootstrap example (generated using chatgpt, so perhaps not so minimal). I run the server by doing `./bin/dev`.

```rb
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown Menu
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Unfortunately the dropdowns don't work.
Even though the `application.js` file contains the line `import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"`, entering Chrome's dev tools JS console, shows `bootstrap` to be an undefined reference.

---

It works if I explicitly import the necessary scripts in the page:

```rb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap Navbar with Dropdown Menu</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown Menu
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- jQuery and Popper.js -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

(I use `render "viewname", layout: false` to avoid the view being embedded in the layout file.)

---

Can someone help me figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I learned (from someone who answered this question on reddit) the code generated by chatgpt uses bootstrap 4, and the options I passed when creating my project sets up rails to use bootstrap 5, which renamed some data attributes (`data-bs-toggle` for what was previously called `data-toggle`).

In the second case, I was importing bootstrap 4 ("thanks" to chatgpt also), which is why it was working.

Hopefully this will help someone else making the same mistake!

Comment: Thus the current policy: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Comment: good policy.. somehow I missed the memo